# WPF ListboxItems Cosume too much memory

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, listbox, listboxitems

Ok i have an WPF application in wich i create my own `ListBoxItem` in a resource dictionary that looks like this :

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="StationItem">
    <Grid x:Name="Gridder" Tag="{Binding SItem.StationName}" Width="125" Height="55">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectagler" Width="120" Height="50" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFF3A00" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE88D20" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="StationName" Text="{Binding SItem.StationName}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="StationCountry" Text="{Binding SItem.StationCountry}" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Light" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,8"/>
        <Image Tag="{Binding SItem.StationName}" Width="15" Height="15" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding FavSource}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,10"/>
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Rectagler" Property="Width" Value="125"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Rectagler" Property="Height" Value="55"/>
            <Setter TargetName="StationName" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

A `ListBox` like this :

```
        <ListBox x:Name="StationsListLB" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource GenreStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ContainerStyle}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="StationsListLB_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" PreviewMouseDoubleClick="StationsListLB_PreviewMouseDoubleClick">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical" MaxHeight="220" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

And i populate my `ListBox` items when the user chooses an Genre of the station, with a method like this :

```
 public class Stations
{
    public StationItem SItem { get; set; }
    public string FavSource { get; set; }
}

public class StationItem
{
    public string StationName { get; set; }
    public string StationUrl { get; set; }
    public string StationGenre { get; set; }
    public string StationWebsite { get; set; }
    public string StationCountry { get; set; }
}

    private void LoadStationByGenre(string Genre)
    {
        StationsListLB.Items.Clear();
        StationsListLB.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("StationItem");

        IEnumerable<Stations> results = StationList.Where(s => s.SItem.StationGenre.Equals(Genre));

        foreach (var Station in results)
        {
            StationsListLB.Items.Add(Station);
        }
    }
```

**Note :** *Every StationGenre will populate my `ListBox` with at least 1000 `StationItems`.*

My code works fine and starts with a memory of 40MB (*Window Task Manager*). But whenever i select a genre and populate my `ListBox`, **memory explodes at 100MB**.And i then select another genre memory explodes further. I thought that with `ListBox.Items.Clear();` the `ListBoxItems` will be destroyed from memory too, but this doesnt happen.

I tried to remove the image from my `ListoBoxItemTemplate` and checked my app's memory, but didnt see a real difference (About 4-7 MB's difference).

**So my answer is** : How can i make my application consume a lot less memory when adding items in the `ListBox`?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Memory leak might be in `Image` control. If you remove this do you still see any substantial growth in memory?

Comment: When i populate the ListBox i get an 100MB memory allocation.If i remove the Image from my DataTemplate i get a little less memory allocation , about 95 MB's.

Comment: How many items you have approximately ? more than 10000 ?

Comment: Maybe you need to try `VirtualizationMode` of `VirtualizingStackPanel`? [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.virtualizationmode.aspx).

Comment: Ehsan my StationList has approximately 7000 Stations. But every genre has 1000 - 1500 stations. Anatoliy im going to check asap and return with my results.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev that worked **PERFECT**. I just replaced my `WrapPanel` with `<VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Orientation="Horizontal" MaxHeight="220" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>` and memory leak dissapearded.Maybe you should post your answer in order to accept it. Thnak you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` to improve performance. Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.virtualizationmode.aspx):

> By default, a VirtualizingStackPanel creates an item container for each visible item and discards it when it is no longer needed (such as when the item is scrolled out of view). When an ItemsControl contains a lot of items, the process of creating and discarding item containers can negatively affect performance. When VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode is set to Recycling, the VirtualizingStackPanel reuses item containers instead of creating a new one each time.